# Problems getting context for translations in react with i18n

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to set up a language switcher in two different apps in my project that share some components between them. In App1 I have the language switcher working properly in my Menu component that is defined extending Component:

```html
class Menu extends Component {
    static contextType = I18nContext;
    [...]
     LangHandler(lng){
        this.context.i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
        history.push(`?lng=${lng}`);
    }
    [...]
     @injectProps
    render({className, Auth, Config, fixed, wWidth, toggle}) {
        const {submenu: {causes, login}, loginOpen, sendingToken, requestLogin} = this;

        const content = (
                        <LangBtn 
                            className={ this.context.i18n.language == "pt" ? "langActive" : "" } 
                            onClick={ this.LangHandler.bind(this, "pt") }>
                                 PT
                        </LangBtn>
                        
                        <LangBtn 
                            className={ this.context.i18n.language == "en" ? "langActive" : "" } 
                            onClick={ this.LangHandler.bind(this, "en") }>
                                 EN
                        </LangBtn>
        );
        return wWidth > phone
            ? content : ReactDOM.createPortal(content, this.container)
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement the language switcher for the other App in the component Header defined like this:

```html
function Header({ match, history }) {
    const langs = useContext(I18nContext);
    function LangHandler(lng){
        langs.i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
        history.push(`?lng=${lng}`);
    }
     return (
        <Main
            fixed={fixed.state}
            height={containerHeight}
            innerRef={container}
        >
            <Container>
                <Route path={match.url} exact>
                    {({match: submatch}) => submatch ? (
                        <a>
                            <img src={logo} alt={name}/>
                        </a>
                    ) : (
                        <Link to={match.url}>
                            <img src={logo} alt={name}/>
                        </Link>
                    )}
                </Route>
                <LangBtn onClick={() => {LangHandler("pt")}}>
                    PT
                </LangBtn>
                
                <LangBtn onClick={() => {LangHandler("en")}}> 
                    EN
                </LangBtn>
            </Container>
        </Main>
    )
}


export default withRouter(Header);
```

This second language switcher is not working, but when i add a console.log:

```
function LangHandler(lng){
    langs.i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    history.push(`?lng=${lng}`);
    console.log(langs.i18n.language)
}
```

it prints the correct language.
Besides not changing the language of other components I'm getting an error (Cannot read property 'language' of undefined) on a Text Component with the following conditional:

```
countries.unshift({ id: null, name: this.context.i18n.language == "pt" ? "Selecione um país" : "Select Country", alpha2: ""});
```

This Text component is used in the firs App and the conditional works like a charm.

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I've got the language switcher working the problem was in App.js I had <I18nProvider> outside of  <BrowserRouter basename={baseHref}>. But I still cannot get the language using this.context on pages where the context was set this way: langs.i18n.changeLanguage(lng);